# Get newly created row id in hibernate native query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

```
sess.createSQLQuery("INSERT INTO ARCHIVE (folder) VALUES(:folder)")
        .setParameter("folder",path)
.executeUpdate();
```

I'd like to have id of newly created object. How can I do that?

Comment: you want to get last inserted rowid, am I right?

Comment: Yes, sure. (have to type something here, because SO don't accept short answers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it

Integer lastId = (Integer) session.createSQLQuery("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()")
        .uniqueResult();

Comment: On mysql it is BigInteger though.