# Hibernate session - how to insert with raw sql and get the generated id?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Using the hibernate session and MySQL, is it possible to insert a row in the database with raw SQL and then get the generated id, within the same transaction (avoiding concurrency issues)?

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (ID int(11) NOT NULL, NAME varchar(50) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID));
```

What I'm doing today:

```
getSession().createSQLQuery("INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (NAME) VALUES ('JOHN')").executeUpdate();
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891130/get-newly-created-row-id-in-hibernate-native-query?

Comment: Offtopic - this makes for an excellent argument for using GUIDs as the PK :) you can generate the ID before the insert.

Comment: I truely believe that there is a way. IT IS Possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be able to use `LAST_INSERT_ID()`; it's determined per-connection, so as long as you call it immediately after the insert, there's no race condition.

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a
>   per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the
>   function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated
>   for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that
>   client. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they
>   generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own. This behavior ensures
>   that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the
>   activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or
>   transactions.

[Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Comment: thanks, didn't know that! Is this the default behavior for others DBMS in general?

Comment: I believe they have different ways of selecting next IDs, so you'd have to check and probably do it differently per DBMS.